# MVC error 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. Works locally but not remotely

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7.5, http-status-code-403

Deployed an MVC5 site on IIS7.5 and receive this error when trying to access remotely:
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
From the server itself, I do not receive the error.
I tried the common suggested fixes like adding

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

to web.config, and running aspnet_regiis for version 4.0.30319, but nothing works.

Months back I had deployed another MVC site (though it was MVC version 3), and it is up and running, without this nonsense.  I can't remember exactly what was done to successfully deploy, but I don't recall headaches like this.  Just out of speculation this wasn't due simply to the newer version of MVC, I copied and pasted the folder of the working MVC3 web app, converted it to an application through IIS, used same app pool, and... receive the remote 403 error on it.  So with an exact copy giving a 403, while the app that I copied works fine, tells me there's some IIS setting I might be missing?  Obviously the web.configs are exactly the same.  Folder permissions look the same. I put a test html page inside the web app folder, and I can access that through a browser remotely. I don't know, I don't spend too much time in IIS configuration hell, and it's frustrating beyond belief.  If anyone has any ideas...

Comment: are the ISAPI modules installed for IIS? http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/isapifilters

Comment: Yes, they are installed.

Comment: Check filesystem permissions for the root of the web application. Default user group I believe is IIS_IUSRS

Comment: Also check that `Anonymous Authentication` is enabled

Comment: Anonymous Authentication is enabled, and IIS_IUSRS have Read&Execute, List Folder contents, and Read permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said that it worked locally the issue must be here:

1. Check your App_Start/BundleConfig.cs file for css references which match the physical folder path of the project.
   Here is an example:

   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include("~/Content/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.css"));

As you can see, **/Content/bootstrap** is also a folder path. What you have to do is, rename this style bundle to something else. Say, "~/Content/bootstrap-css". Basically, it shouldn't match a physical folder path.

I had this problem, it works locally but not on the server. So, it should help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Check the Basic Settings for your domain in IIS.  Set it to DefaultAppPool.  This resolved the same issue for me.